# MySQL - join returning "preferred row"

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, alliance (a) and alliance_user (au) maintaining a relationship between users and allies in an online game.

Alliance table's primary key is referenced in the alliance_user table and may occur many times. Example:

```
a.id | a.name          | au.id | au.username | au.user_role            
-----+-----------------+-------+-------------+------------------------
1    | First Alliance  | 1     | JohnnyA     | Alliance Founder        
1    | First Alliance  | 2     | JohnnyA     | Trusted Alliance Member 
2    | Second Alliance | 3     | JohnnyB     | Alliance Founder        
3    | Third Alliance  | 4     | JohnnyC     | Trusted Alliance Member
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`name`, `au`.`id`, `au`.`username`, `au`.`user_role`
FROM `alliance` `a`
INNER JOIN `alliance_user` `au` ON `au`.`alliance_id` = `a`.`id`
WHERE `au`.`username` = 'JohnnyA'
AND `au`.`user_role` IN('Alliance Founder', 'Trusted Alliance Member')
```

I am getting this (correct as per my query):

```
a.id | a.name          | au.id | au.username | au.user_role            
-----+-----------------+-------+-------------+------------------------
1    | First Alliance  | 1     | JohnnyA     | Alliance Founder        
1    | First Alliance  | 2     | JohnnyA     | Trusted Alliance Member
```

But I want this:

```
a.id | a.name          | au.id | au.username | au.user_role            
-----+-----------------+-------+-------------+-----------------
1    | First Alliance  | 1     | JohnnyA     | Alliance Founder
```

But in the case of JohnnyC, I want to get this:

```
a.id | a.name          | au.id | au.username | au.user_role            
-----+-----------------+-------+-------------+------------------------
3    | Third Alliance  | 4     | JohnnyC     | Trusted Alliance Member
```

As he is not an alliance founder, but still privileged to see the information requested.

The question can be asked whether JohnnyA should not have a distinct role in his alliance, and that is a valid question, and I may still implement it as such, but for me it is more about finding out if what I want to do is possible in a single query instead of having to process the data afterwards with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  try using an order by FIELD based  on  au.user_role 
and limit 1

```
    SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`name`, `au`.`id`, `au`.`username`, `au`.`user_role`
    FROM `alliance` `a`
    INNER JOIN `alliance_user` `au` ON `au`.`alliance_id` = `a`.`id`
    WHERE `au`.`username` = 'JohnnyA'
    AND `au`.`user_role` IN('Alliance Founder', 'Trusted Alliance Member') 
    ORDER BY FIEDL(au.user_role ,'Alliance Founder' , 'Trusted Alliance Member')
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Trying it now, thanks a lot! Just concerned about one thing with this, is the use of the limit modifier, because technically, it is possible that this same player can play MANY worlds (I did not bring the worlds into this query for simplicity) but I could be playing in 20 worlds, and my table listing uses a pager of 15 rows, so the limit of 1 would interfere with the pager. Is there a way around that or not?

Comment: Your solution works for the original question asked. Thank you. I will accept your answer. I think I will have to stick to a single role for a user in an alliance. It does make sense in this particular case to prevent duplicate roles any way.

Comment: What I meant was that JohnnyA could be a player in worlds 1 - 20, and my tabular listing has a pager of 15 rows. So - listing JohnnyA's roles in all worlds he is playing will result in a 2-page table, and the limit(1) will break the pager. But you have answered the question as asked, and it works. Thank you :-)

Comment: @KobusMyburgh    you could post a new question with a proper data sample and the expected result for your comment  .. and eventually comment me the new link